# Bootstrap accordion scrolling behaviour on collapse

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 accordion. 
After reading numerous posts on how to have independent behaviour on the contents, rather than keeping only one active by default, i use **data-target** and the id if the content instead of the default **data-parent** of the accordion id.
The independent collapsing works fine, but now on collapse it scrolls to the top of the collapsible item.
How can I disable this scrolling behaviour whilst keeping the collapsible in-dependancy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think i know what causes the scrolling problem.
If you are based on the example shown in [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), then you probably use anchors

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-content="#your-content" href="#your-content">...</a>
```

instead of anchors you can use spans

```
<span data-toggle="collapse" data-content="#your-content">...<span>
```

The href in the anchor is causing the scroll.
I hope that helps

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. The anchors were messing with the page scroll behaviour. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `class="your-header-class"` to the `a header` element:

```
<a class="your-header-class" data-toggle="collapse" data-content="#your-content" href="#your-content">...</a>
```

and then add this:

```
$('.your-header-class').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using `button` just changed it to `div`.