# Bootstrap accordion displaying blurred text on toggle and scroll

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have this weird problem that I am facing on chrome for my bootstrap accordion, where whenever i toggle the accordion from its default state,

The text seems to become darker and at times blurred from time to time on chrome,

```
<div class="accordionbg">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group panel">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse295" id="accordion4">
                        <i></i>Certification </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse295" class="accordion-body collapse in" style="height: auto;">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <p>On successful completions of assignments &amp; projects, you will be provided a Skillspeed certificate stating your satisfactory performance on the course.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    .......

</div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstraps default accordion and there is no being applied inside the accordion, the page can be accessed at [this site here](http://skillspeed.com/course/android-app-development/)

I have done some research and it could be because of css3 transitions being applied, but I am totally clueless. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: have you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489625/bootstrap-accordion-scrolling-behaviour-on-collapse?rq=1

Comment: my question is something completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this problem myself before on Chrome and though not entirely satisfactory I opted for using

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
```

on the affected elements (p,h1 etc).. it basically 'flattens' the text and I can't isolate where the shadow is being pulled in between the different plugin files etc in your example. You can read more about webkit-transform [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp)if you want to know more.

It's bad practice but you could just apply that code to your

```
    <body>
```

element.

You're also calling in the Roboto font without the bold font-weight variation in your skillspeed.css file, so the browser is rendering a 'faux' bold which doesn't help matters either. Try replacing the link in your @import with
'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' to help matters too.

Comment: Thanks, that made sense. I'll try it out to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried the 1. answer's solution, but it did not worked form me in Chrome (sorry). I use a "transform: rotate(-1deg)" for the text-box and another rotate back like rotate(1deg) for the text inside the box to read it horizontally. That is why my text was blurry. My solution is to put the whole div in another div and style it like rotate(0deg). Like this:

```
<div class="outside-fix-box" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);">
   <div class="rotated-text-box" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);">
      <p class="rotate-back-text" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);">
         The text...
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

After styling the "ouside-fix-box" my text turned sharp again. I hope this will help you too!